# Early 90s story of kids shot into space in "pod" as trial by ordeal

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, science

I read a story (in the early 90s) about kids who faced some kind of trial by ordeal where they were shot into space (I think) in what I remember to be "pods". Does this ring a bell with anyone?

I think I received this story (either in an anthology or as a novel) from the Science Fiction Book Club in the early 90s.

Comment: I recall a Piers Anthony book where young aliens are made to compete in a race around their solar system, but I don't recall the title or any more details.  The ships may have been pods (living spaceships of some sort, I think?)

Comment: Please add any more details about the story that you can think of.

Comment: Sounds kind of like [Explorers](http://www.river-phoenix.org/bookshelf/explorers-novel/)!

Answer (score 3):

[*Going to See the End of the Sky*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?15701) by William John Watkins, printed in 1986?

Part of the synopsis on the back cover:

> "Catchcage, first of the habitats of the Legrange league, where everyone was a prophet or a madman. Only Catchcagers risked the annual ore pod journey through the vacuum to a frightening face-off with death."

Comment: I'm not sure that was a Science Fiction Book Club selection, but the OP may have remembered that wrong. Could you please indicate how that book matches the plot description?

Comment: part of the synopsis on the back cover-  "Catchage, first of the habitats of the Legrange league, where everyone was a prophet or a madman.  only Catchcagers risked the annual ore pod journey through the vacuum to a frightening face-off with death."

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Invitation to the Game by Monica Hughes? 
Set in the future, unemployment rates are high, so the government tightly regulates unemployeds. Some kids graduate and are immediately classified unemployed, eventually get into The Game where they do survival simulations of an alien planet.